# Using lambda function to connect buttons in a calculator program and show values after entering

Tags: python, lambda, pygtk

So I am trying to work with the lambda function to connect the buttons of my calculator with a function. Here is some of my code:

```
button1 = Gtk.Button(label = "1")
lambda event: self.button_clicked(event, "1"), button1
vbox.pack_start(button1 ,True, True, 0)
vbox.pack_end(button1,True,True,0)
self.add(button1)
```

So I basically want to calculate two numbers when they are clicked but before that I want to to display them in the entry of course. But when I click `button1` for example it doesn't get displayed in the text entry. That's basically the problem I need to solve. I think that the button_clicked function should work with all the ifs. That is basically my problem.

```
def button_clicked(self, value):
    if (value != None):
        if (value != "="):
            # Add something to the text
            self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str(value))
        else:
            # Evaluate the text
            self.result = eval(self.entry.get_text())
            self.entry.set_text(self.result)
    else:
        # Clear the text
        self.entry.set_text("")
```

Am I using the lambda function the right way? And if not how can I change the code?

Comment: `lambda event: self.button_clicked(event, "1"), button1` does nothing as-is. Can you fix your indentation? because it is completely off.

Comment: If the button does what you want it to do when you click it then you did it the right way. That is a more reliable test then posting code on Stack Overflow and asking people who don't know what you want to do if you have done what you want to do. If it fails your own test, *then* post a question which describes how it fails.

Comment: I edited my question I hope it makes my problem clear.

Comment: The button click doesn't do anything because you haven't attached any click handler. You create a lambda and then just throw it away. You need to actually add it as a callback e.g.: `button1.connect('clicked', lambda ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've now asked similar questions multiple times, this is how it would basically look:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from gi.repository import Gtk

class Window(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.connect('delete-event', Gtk.main_quit)

        grid = Gtk.Grid()
        for i in range(10):
            button = Gtk.Button(label=str(i))
            button.connect('clicked', self.number_clicked, i)
            grid.attach(button, i%3, i//3, 1, 1)

        self.entry = Gtk.Entry()
        button = Gtk.Button(label='=')
        button.connect('clicked', self.solve_clicked)
        vbox = Gtk.VBox()
        vbox.pack_start(self.entry, False, False, 0)
        vbox.pack_start(grid, True, True, 0)
        vbox.pack_start(button, False, False, 0)

        self.add(vbox)
        self.show_all()

    def number_clicked(self, button, i):
        self.entry.set_text(self.entry.get_text() + str(i))

    def solve_clicked(self, button):
        # here should be the parser for the mathematical expression
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window()
    Gtk.main()
```